# DHCP Server (v4_4_2) from sources fails to start

Tags: dhcpd

When build DHCP from sources and trying to run the DHCP server, failing with ERROR. Any ideas what could the issue, something related how **build** from sources or something else is missing?
No issues if install the DHCP Server from package(sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server).

**ERROR**:

```
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: Unknown command -user
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: Usage: dhcpd [-p <UDP port #>] [-f] [-d] [-q] [-t|-T]
                                                [-4|-6] [-cf config-file] [-lf lease-file]
                                                [-tf trace-output-file]
                                                [-play trace-input-file]
                                                [-pf pid-file] [--no-pid] [-s server]
                                                [if0 [...ifN]]
                                          dhcpd {--version|--help|-h}
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]:
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]:
Jun 09 20:02:16  dhcpd[1531]: exiting.
```

**Details**:

Ubuntu: 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Script to build DHCP from sources:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Define variable
DHCP_VER="v4_4_2"

# Install libary for build DHCP server
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade
sudo apt -y install libtool build-essential autoconf automake g++

# Preparation
if ! [ -d ~/build ]; then
    mkdir ~/build
fi

cd ~/build

git clone https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp.git -b ${DHCP_VER}

cd ~/build/dhcp

autoreconf -i

CFLAGS="-D_PATH_DHCLIENT_SCRIPT='\"/sbin/dhclient-script\"'             \
        -D_PATH_DHCPD_CONF='\"/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf\"'                   \
        -D_PATH_DHCLIENT_CONF='\"/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf\"'"

./configure --prefix=/usr                                           \
            --sysconfdir=/etc/dhcp                                  \
            --localstatedir=/var                                    \
            --with-srv-lease-file=/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases       \
            --with-srv6-lease-file=/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd6.leases     \
            --with-cli-lease-file=/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient.leases \
            --with-cli6-lease-file=/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient6.leases

# Make and install DHCP 
make >make.out 2>&1
make install    
    
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing configuration property. Please add **--enable-paranoia** to the configure flags.

```
./configure --enable-paranoia
            --prefix=/usr                                           \
            --sysconfdir=/etc/dhcp                                  \
            --localstatedir=/var                                    \
            --with-srv-lease-file=/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases        \
            --with-srv6-lease-file=/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases      \
            --with-cli-lease-file=/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient.leases \
            --with-cli6-lease-file=/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient6.leases
```